# Validation errors on grid not appearing

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services, validation

I have bound a DataGrid in Silverlight via WCF RIA services and have custom server-side only validators in place.  When I edit the grid in a way that violates these custom validations and click a SubmitChanges button, the errors do not appear immediately.  If I click around the field they will appear, but I thought they were supposed to show up right away.  If I make my custom validator shared it works client-side without an issue.  Do I need to call a method to make these validation errors appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because errors are tied to a specific row.  Normally with client-side validators you cannot leave the current row until you have addressed errors.